# Css variable interpolation Styled Components

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, styled-components, css-variables

I have a component for example:

```
const pretty = styled.div`
  --nth-child: 5n;
  --size: 20px; //css variable
  
  width: var(--size);

  &:nth-child(var(--nth-child)) {
    //...styles...
  }

  @media (max-width: 768px) {
    //overriding
    --size: 12px;
    --nth-child: 3n;
  }
`
```

The question is how to interpolate css variable in this place?

```
&:nth-child(var(--nth-child)) {
  //...styles...
}
```

If I understood correctly this is impossible so it would be nice to find another solution

**Note:**  I can't use JS variables in my case

**Update:**

Also editor highlights the error there:

[image]

so I tried this, but this does not work either:

```
&:nth-child(${css`var(--nth-child)`}) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

Comment: Change the custom property to be `5n` not `5`?

Comment: @evolutionxbox, I tried, this is not working yet

Comment: It’s not possible sadly. https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2018/05/css-custom-properties-strategy-guide/

Comment: @evolutionxbox, as I thought. It's a pity that styled-components do not have any hack for this

Comment: IMO it is not even probable that `var` will be supported in selectors in the future: technically those are not variables but *properties* so they make sense only as property of some *element*. Imagine hypothetical outcome of `el:nth-child(var(--nr)){--nr:calc(var(--nr)+1)}`.

Comment: I'm not sure how they could... it's not a JS thing. CSS "variables" are calculated at runtime and are not simple string replacments like SASS or LESS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you can't use CSS variables for anything but property declarations. They don't work in selectors.

But I think you should be able to achieve the same here by other means. I know you mentioned `I can't use JS variables in my case` and probably your usecase is less straightforward than the example, but can't you either just use React props interpolation that comes with `styled-components`

```
&:nth-child(${p => p.nthChildLargeScreen}) {
  //...styles...
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
  &:nth-child(${p => p.nthChildLargeScreen}) {
    //...reverse styles from above...
  }

  &:nth-child(${p => p.nthChildSmallScreen}) {
    //...styles...
  }
}
```

Or even just global variables?

```
&:nth-child(${NTH_CHILD_LARGE_SCREEN}) {
  //...styles...
}

...etc
```

If you can write the styled component, and define CSS variables, in the first place, seems like you should be able to do at least one of the above instead.

Comment: The first piece of code will not work because the `nth-child(3)` in the media query does not override the current (`nth-child(5)`)

Comment: Also found another solution (it does not apply to the question) but it is so creepy that I think the community should not see this. Closing a question..

Comment: Right you are! Good spot, I guess this shows up why hardcoding is less elegant in the first place. Come to think of it' I'll just remove that whole section, I guess the whole reason you wanted to use CSS variables was to avoid that